# How to add xml declration in my final html file with thymeleaf

Tags: html, xml, spring, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf and Spring to return to my users html file.

I have added this XML declaration in the first line of my html file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But I think it was deleted by thymeleaf engine

How can I do to have this xml declaration in my file?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `setTemplateMode` in `ViewResolver` to value 'XML'.
If you are using version 2.0.2 :

```
// Thymeleaf configuration
//...
ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
templateResolver.setTemplateMode("XML");
templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
templateResolver.setSuffix(".xml");
//...
```

If you using the newest version - 3.0.X, then :

```
private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.XML);
    return resolver;
}
```

Example for Thymeleaf 2 [is here](http://javabeat.net/thymeleaf-hello-world-example/).
More info for Thymeleaf 3 in [this official Thymeleaf 3 reference](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html).

Comment: Sanluck        I've tried what you told me but I am using Spring boot and when I ru my project I have know this exception :java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration due to org/thymeleaf/resourceresolver/IResourceResolver not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)